# project name not found in angular

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-seo

I am trying to convert my angular app to angular universal. I keep getting the error saying:

> Project 'my-app' could not be found in Workspace.

when I try to build the app using:

`npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server`

**app.module.ts:**

`BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'techstack21-angular'}),`

**Angular.json:**

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "./dist/techstack21-angular",
    "main": "src/main.server.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
  }
},
```

**tsconfig.app.json:**

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../dist/techstack21-angular",
  "module": "es2015",
  "types": ["node"],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
},
```

**Package.json:**

```
 "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app:server",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve": "node server.js"
```

I tried deleting the `node_modules` folder but I get the same error again. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the complete error which shows up... Also package.json also

Comment: @yurzui updated the question with package.json

Comment: @yurzui thank you. That was the problem. I replaced it with project name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your own project name in `build:client-and-server-bundles` script:

**package.json**

```
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run my-app:server",
                                                              ^^^^^^
                                                  replace with your projectName
```